# List items of each order in one row in SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of orders. I want to obtain table 2 from table 1.

Table1:

| OrderID | ItemId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Table2:

| OrderID | Items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"ItemId":1},{"ItemId":2}] |
| 2 | [{"ItemId":3}] |

How can I obtain table 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, I use `FOR JSON` to format `SELECT` result as JSON. The `FOR JSON` clause format the query results as JSON, instead of table.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
  T1.[OrderID],
  (SELECT T2.ItemId FROM OrderTable T2 WHERE T1.OrderID=T2.OrderID FOR JSON PATH) AS Items
  FROM OrderTable  AS T1
  GROUP BY T1.[OrderID]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2017 or above, there is `STRING_AGG` function that will do exactly this for you:

```
SELECT OrderId, '[' + STRING_AGG('{"ItemId":' + ItemId + "}, ',') + ']' AS ItemId FROM Table1;
```

However, looking at the concatenated value, it looks like you're trying to construct JSON output in your SQL query. If that is the case, you'd better be off doing this in the application layer, or using `FOR JSON` construct as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).